# c _Generic and macro funtion

Tags: c, function, generics, macros

I'm writing `DEBUG_MSG` for print debug messages

```
#define DEBUG_MSG(msg_str) _DEBUG_MSG_GENERIC(msg_str)
```

The `_DEBUG_MSG_GENERIC` is because I'd like to:

- Show `int` message when a input parameter is `int`
- Show `char*` message when a input parameter is `char*`

and its implement:

```
#define _DEBUG_MSG_GENERIC(strs) \
  _Generic( (strs), \
             int: _DEBUG_MSG_INT, \
             default: _DEBUG_MSG_STR \
          )(strs)
```

Now I'd like to implement `_DEBUG_MSG_INT` and `_DEBUG_MSG_STR` with Macro function and `printf` :

```
#define _DEBUG_MSG_INT(val) printf("%d\n", val);
#define _DEBUG_MSG_STR(str) printf("%s\n", str);
```

But I got error message is:

```
main.c:14:30: error: ‘_DEBUG_MSG_INT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘DEBUG_MSG’?
   14 |                         int: _DEBUG_MSG_INT, \
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I solve it?

Does `_generic` only support function(pointer to function) and not support macro function?

### Full Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG_MSG(msg_str) _DEBUG_MSG_GENERIC(msg_str)
#define _DEBUG_MSG_GENERIC(strs) \
            _Generic( (strs), \
                        int: _DEBUG_MSG_INT, \
                      default: _DEBUG_MSG_STR \
                    )(strs)
#define _DEBUG_MSG_INT(val) printf("%d\n", val)
#define _DEBUG_MSG_STR(str) printf("%s\n", str)

int main()
{
    DEBUG_MSG("str");
    DEBUG_MSG(5);
}
```

Comment: You *can* use macro functions in generic statements, but there must be nothing between the macro identifier and the argument list. For example, changing `_DEBUG_MSG_INT,` to `_DEBUG_MSG_INT(strs),` *would be* recognized by the preprocessor as a macro function. Unfortunately doing so will generate warnings for other reasons (even after you remove `(strs)` that follows the  `_Generic` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that both `_DEBUG_MSG_INT` and `_DEBUG_MSG_STR` are function-like macros thus they are only expanded if they are followed by `()`.

Note that macro expansion takes place before actual C compilation thus `_Generic` is nothing more than a common identifier at preprocessor stage.

I suggest using `_Generic` not for selection of the function pointer but rather for a formatting specifier to be used in `printf()`. Try:

```
#define _DEBUG_MSG_GENERIC(arg) printf( _DEBUG_MSG_FMTSPEC(arg), arg)
#define _DEBUG_MSG_FMTSPEC(arg) \
  _Generic( (arg), int: "%d\n", default: "%s\n")
```

Comment: Oh~ thank you so much! I didn't think of it could be used for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is because the preprocessor only makes one pass of the source code, so the `printf`'s don't get substituted.

A quick solution would be to define `_DEBUG_MSG_INT(val)` and `_DEBUG_MSG_STR(str)` as real functions like so:

```
void _DEBUG_MSG_INT(int val) {
    printf("%d\n", val);
}
void _DEBUG_MSG_STR(char * str) {
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

The compiler will optimise out the extra function call overhead and will behave as if you called `printf` directly.

Comment: Thanks your reply. Actually, I use this version now, but I replace `void` with `static inline void`. It may eliminate cost of function call. But `inline` seems can't guarantee RVO to eliminate cost of function call.

Comment: Use of `inline` can depend on your compiler's language/standard setting. Strict C89/C90/ANSI didn't have the `inline` keyword at all.
In most cases it's only a hint to the compiler and it may not actually inline it. Typically small functions get inlined anyway, unless you take the function's address or a few other things.

Comment: @gengumby, using `static inline` allows using those function in the headers. Otherwise the compilation of multiple translation units will likely fail due to multiple definitions of those functions

Comment: @tstanisl A slight nitpick: it allows multiple translation units to see the definition and not just the declaration, thereby letting the compiler inline that function in many places (as it sees fit). It needs to be declared `static` in the header because there's no guarantee it will inline _all_ uses, and so must have only one definition/instance across all translation units.

Answer (score 1):

`_Generic` is not a preprocessor operation and cannot be used to select preprocessor macro functions. The code after a `:` in its cases must be a C expression (specifically an *assignment-expression*).

The code you have in those positions is `_DEBUG_MSG_INT` and `_DEBUG_MSG_STR`. Those are preprocessor macro names.

Those preprocessor macros are function-like macros. They are macro-replaced only when they are followed by a `(`. In your code, there is no `(` after them, so they are not replaced.

That means the code after reprocessing looks like `int : _DEBUG_MSG_INT,`. So the compiler attempts to interpret `_DEBUG_MSG_INT` as an expression. Since `_DEBUG_MSG_INT` is not a declared identifier, the compiler reports an error that it is undeclared.

In summary, your code `_Generic( (strs), int: _DEBUG_MSG_INT, default: _DEBUG_MSG_STR )(strs)` attempts to use an after-preprocessing `_Generic` selection to select a preprocessing-time macro (either `_DEBUG_MSG_INT` or `_DEBUG_MSG_STR`) and then to have that macro treated as a function-like macros with the `(strs)` that appears after the `_Generic`. That simply cannot work; an after-preprocessing `_Generic` cannot select preprocessing macro names.